# Show that $(C^{k}([0,1],F),\left \| . \right \|_{C^{k}})$ is banach , where $(F,\left \| . \right \|_{F})$ is banach

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces, banach-spaces, cauchy-sequences, topological-groups

Show that $(C^{k}([0,1],F),\left \| . \right \|_{C^{k}})$ is banach , where  $(F,\left \| . \right \|_{F})$ is banach and $\left \| f \right \|_{C^{k}}=\sum_{j=0}^{k}\left \| f^{(j)} \right \|_{\infty}$
$\forall (f_{n})_{n}\subset (C^{k}([0,1],F),\left \| . \right \|_{C^{k}})$ Cauchy ie $\forall \epsilon>0,\exists N\in\mathbb{N},\forall n \geqslant N$ and $\forall p \geq N\Rightarrow \left \| f_{n}-f_p\right \|_{C^{k}}\leqslant \epsilon$. for $x$ fixed, $\left \| f_{n}(x)-f_{p}(x) \right \|_{F}\leqslant \left \| f_{n}-f_{p} \right \|_{\infty}\leqslant \left \| f_{n}-f_{p} \right \|_{C^{k}}$.So $(f_{n}(x))$ is cauchy and $(F,\left \| . \right \|_{F})$ is banach, so $(f_{n}(x))_{n}$ we call it f(x). I'm stuck here. Thank you.

Comment: do $k = 0$ first (you are most of the way done with it). See what progress you can make towards the general case by using the $k = 0$ result. An argument involving the fundamental theorem of calculus is one way to complete the proof for general $k$.

Comment: for $k=0$, by limit $p \rightarrow +\infty , \left \| f_{n}(x)-f(x) \right \|_{F}\leq \epsilon.$ Then by using the sup, $\left \| f_{n}-f \right \|_{\infty}\leq \epsilon$.
Let show that $f$ is continous. $(f_{n}(x))_{n} \subset C^{0}([0,1],F)$ in particular $f_{N}(x)$ is continuous.
$\left \| f(x)-f(y) \right \|_{F}\leq \left \| f(x)-f_{N}(x) \right \|_{F}+\left \| f_{N}(x)-f_{N}(y) \right \|_{F}+\left \| f_{N}(y)-f(y) \right \|_{F}\leq 3\epsilon$