# $(L_{c}(E,F),\left \| . \right \|_{E\rightarrow F})$ Banach $\Leftrightarrow (F,\left \| . \right \|_{F})$ Banach

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, general-topology, uniform-convergence, supremum-and-infimum

Let $(\varphi_{n}) \subset (L_{c}(E,F),\left \| . \right \|_{E\rightarrow F})$ Cauchy.
$\left \| \varphi_{n}-\varphi_{p} \right \|_{E\rightarrow F}=sup_{\left \| x \right \|\leqslant 1}\left \| \varphi_n(x)-\varphi_{p}(x) \right \|_{F}\leq \epsilon$.
$(\varphi_{n})_{x \in B(0,1),n}$ converge continuously to $\varphi$ because bounded and F is banach.
$\forall x \in E$ but not in $B(0,1)$ $\varphi_{n}(x)=\varphi_{n}(\frac{x}{\left \| x \right \|})\times\left \| x \right \|\rightarrow \varphi(x)$.
For $N\geqslant 0, \varphi_{N}$ is continuous, $\left \| \varphi(x)-\varphi(y) \right \| \leqslant \left \| \varphi(x)-\varphi_{N}(x) \right \|+\left \| \varphi_{N}(x)-\varphi_{N}(y) \right \|+\left \| \varphi_{N}(y)-\varphi(y) \right \|\leqslant 3\epsilon$, $\forall x,y \in E$
It is correct ?

Comment: I can’t say I followed much of that. Are you just trying to show the $\impliedby$ direction? If so, what is the limit of $\varphi_n$? Where do you construct it? How do you know it’s linear? How do you know it’s continuous?

Comment: Sorry, I just wrote the main idea. Yes I just want to show that implication first, The idea is to construct the limit of $\varphi_{n}$ by using the fact that F is banach. Because $\varphi_{n}(x)$ is cauchy in F. Linear is fine : $\varphi(x+\lambda y)=lim_{n} \varphi_{n}(x+\lambda y) = lim_{n} \varphi_{n}(x)+\lambda \varphi_{n}(y) = \varphi(x)+\lambda \varphi(y)$. For the continuous part I take x,y such as $|x-y|<\delta \Rightarrow |\varphi_{N}(x)-\varphi_{N}(y)|<\epsilon$ and $\varphi_{N}(x)$ converge to $\varphi(x)$.

Comment: In the third line u mean $\phi_{n} (x) $, right? This sequence converge for every $x$ because it is Cauchy in $F$, which is complete.anf'd how u choose $N$?

Comment: Ok so you’re defining $\varphi$ as a pointwise limit of $\varphi_n$. That makes sense, and is a common approach. Your proof of linearity is fine. Your proof of continuity is, again, not particularly comprehensible (you can’t just *pick* $x$ and $y$), but you sound confident that you’re ok with it, so I’ll chalk it up to brevity. You still need to show that the pointwise limit $\varphi$ is the limit, in norm, of $\varphi_n$.

Comment: Sorry again for this forgotten, I choose N by the defition of cauchy 
$\forall \epsilon>0, \exists N \geqslant 0, \forall n,p \geqslant N, ||\varphi_{n}(x)-\varphi_{p}(x)||_{F}<\epsilon$.
For the commentary on the third line I'm not sure what do you mean by that. thank you

Comment: @TheoBendit I'm not confident at all ! haha. Do you have any advice to prove the continuous part ? 
By limit $p \rightarrow +\infty, ||\varphi_{n}(x)-\varphi_{p}(x)||_{F} \rightarrow  ||\varphi_{n}(x)-\varphi(x)||_{F}$ then I don't know how to continue from this point. thank you

Comment: @Loca My advice with continuity is not to use the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition, but instead show the linear map is bounded, i.e. there exists some $K$ such that, for all $x$, $\|\varphi(x)\| \le K\|x\|$. You can take $K$ to be any upper bound on $(\|\varphi_n\|)_n$, or with a bit more work, even $K = \lim_{n \to \infty} \|\varphi_n\|$ (note: $\|\varphi_n\|$ is a Cauchy sequence). Here, the pointwise convergence of $\varphi_n(x)$ to $\varphi(x)$ will come in handy.

Comment: @Loca As for my remark about needing to show the pointwise limit $\varphi$ is the limit of $\varphi_n$ in norm, what you have proven (or really, defined) so far is that, for all $x \in E$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \varphi_n(x) = \varphi(x)$. What you want to do is show that $\|\varphi_n - \varphi\| = \sup_{x \in B[0; 1]} \|\varphi_n(x) - \varphi(x)\|$ converges to $0$ as $n \to \infty$, i.e. $\varphi_n$ approaches $\varphi$ *uniformly on the unit ball*. Pointwise convergence is weaker than strong convergence. It's good to construct $\varphi$ with pointwise convergence, but more argument is needed.

Comment: A cauchy sequence is bounded by definition, $\exists M>0 $ such as $\forall n, ||\varphi_{n}(x)||_{F}\leqslant M$.
Can I write : $||\varphi_{n}(\frac{x}{||x||})||_{F}\leqslant M \Rightarrow ||\varphi_{n}(x)||_{F}\leqslant M ||x||$ than conclude by limit ?

Comment: @TheoBendit Sorry I need more advice to show the convergence, but your explaination are very clear thank you! I have the same issue on my other post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4568721/show-that-ck0-1-f-left-right-ck-is-banach-where-f?noredirect=1#comment9613565_4568721

Comment: @Loca No, you can't, I'm afraid. The problem is, $M$ depends on $x$ here. You need a bound that works for all $x$. This is why I suggest using an upper bound on $\|\phi_n\|$, rather than $\|\phi_n(x)\|$.

Comment: I have an another idea : $||\varphi_{n}(x)||_{F} \leqslant ||\varphi_{n}||_{E \rightarrow F} \times ||x||$ but here again I use x, after edit, $ ||\varphi_{n}||_{E \rightarrow F} $ is Cauchy it bounded we can conclude that $||\varphi_{n}(x)||_{F} \leqslant M\times ||x||$

Comment: @Loca Yes, exactly! That works.

Comment: thank you so much !